# Deleting a file always fails

Tags: java, file, delete-file

I've been trying to delete a file from a jlist on the press of a button but it always seems to fail. I know the path that I'm getting from the jlist is correct because I am able to open the file and I've also tried using this code to delete a file using an absolute path. Does anybody see any errors here or something I'm doing wrong?

```
JButton btnDeleteLog = new JButton("Delete Log");
btnDeleteLog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try{
            File file = new File("C:/ProgramData/Logs/" + selectedJLItem);
            file.delete();
            if(file.delete()){
                System.out.println(file.getName() + " Was deleted!");
                ClientWindow.console(file.getName() + " Was Deleted Successfully!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Delete Operation Failed. Check: " + file);
                ClientWindow.console("Failed To Delete " + file.getName());
            }
        }catch(Exception e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: So `file.delete()` returns `false`? What's the name of the file? Is any other process using it?

Comment: First chk if it is accessible by using isExist and chk if it is not opened by any other program

Comment: store the return value of file.delete() in a boolean and check the boolean instead of invoking delete twice.

Comment: Can you as a user delete the file? If it fails to delete, it might be a permissions issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to delete a file twice.

First:

`file.delete();`

Second:

`if(file.delete()){
  // some processing here
}`

Instead, try to do so:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         try{
             File file = new File("C:/ProgramData/Logs/" + selectedJLItem);

             if(file.delete()){
                 System.out.println(file.getName() + " Was deleted!");
             }else{
                 System.out.println("Delete Operation Failed. Check: " + file);
             }
         }catch(Exception e1){
             e1.printStackTrace();
         }    
    }
}
```

This is the right way and you get:

`Example.txt Was deleted!`

Comment: Yeah I caught this a few hours after I had posted and it wouldn't let me answer it for myself for like 8 hours or something. Odd thing is the file never got deleted (I looked for it instead of relying on a sysout) until I removed the first delete ().